When using shadcn-vue carousel does not work
I am using vue-vite with typescript, when copy and pasting the code
from https://www.shadcn-vue.com/docs/components/carousel.html it shows something
like this
Does somebody has an idea of why it does not work, or where might be the source of the problem :[
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Carousel, CarouselContent, CarouselItem, CarouselNext, CarouselPrevious } from '@/components/ui/carousel'
import { Card, CardContent } from '@/components/ui/card'
</script>

<template>
  <Carousel class="relative w-full max-w-xs">
    <CarouselContent>
      <CarouselItem v-for="(_, index) in 5" :key="index">
        <div class="p-1">
          <Card>
            <CardContent class="flex aspect-square items-center justify-center p-6">
              <span class="text-4xl font-semibold">{{ index + 1 }}</span>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </div>
      </CarouselItem>
    </CarouselContent>
    <CarouselPrevious />
    <CarouselNext />
  </Carousel>
</template>

this is the code that i copy and pasted from the page

Did you follow the steps outlined in Installation > Vite? When you run npx shadcn-vue@latest init in step 6, you should have all carousel components in src/components/ui/ folder. Please note your question is not currently answerable. Please share a runnable [mcve]. Use codesandbox.io or similar.
